# Pushing packages to private nuget repository

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

So I just set up a local nuget repository by following [these](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/wiki/Hosting-the-NuGet-Gallery-Locally-in-IIS) steps, and I got everything working ok except for pushing packages from the command line.

I can push them via the website and they show up as they should. But when I run the command `nuget push mypackage.1.0.0.nupkg <myapikeyhere> -source http://mylocalserver`, all I get is

> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

So any ideas what might be the problem here? Haven't found much help via google, mostly the problems seem to be related to being unable to upload any packages at all.

Comment: Is it possible that you're using an incompatible version of nuget?  As in your client and server have different versions?

Comment: Just checked, they both have 3.3.x